# How do I provide a default class definition from /lib in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm presently using a git subtree to manage a directory of classes/libraries somewhere under `/lib`. The idea is to share common classes and libraries from that directory between different projects that I manage. In it are default implementations of various classes, such as models, controllers, etc. The desired result is that any application I set up which has this subtree would not HAVE to define or customize the classes that come with default implementations, but can if needed.

For example, I have a default `User` model, and wish to include it automatically so that there is no need to define one in `/app/models`. The problem is that if I DO automatically include it, and then additionally define a `User` class in `/app/models` (say to add or override a method or some configs), that definition will never be included because the class already exists.

I'm attempting to take advantage of the fact that a class can be defined twice in Ruby, and it'll more or less "merge" the definitions. For example, defining a `User` class twice in the following way will result in a single `User` class with methods for both `User.foo` and `User.bar`:

```
class User
  def self.foo; 'foo'; end
end

class User
  def self.bar; 'bar'; end
end
```

The best way I've come up with to do this so far is to write code in an initializer like the following (note that the `to_underscores` method isn't a standard `String` method, it's my own):

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  [
    User,
    # more classes...
  ].each do |klass|
    filepath = Rails.root.join("app/models/#{klass.name.to_underscores}.rb")
    require filepath if File.exist? filepath
  end
end
```

I could clean this up a bit perhaps by looping through class definitions which exist in key subdirectories under `/lib` so I don't have to manually list out class names that can be extended/overridden in this way, but I feel like there's got to be a better way. This list will be pretty long and a little silly to try and manage, not to mention it'll be a lot trickier with classes defined in a directory structure with subdirectories. I'd like something more automatic. Any thoughts??

Comment: A class cannot be defined twice in ruby. You can reopen a class definition and add/remove/alter functionality in the class but it is still the same class.

Comment: @engineersmnky Perhaps I'm using the wrong terms when I say I'm defining it twice, but I think you get the idea. I want two definitions to be loaded. Perhaps the second one, as you say, is only "reopening" the original. That's fine. I just need both definitions loaded if a second one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use inheritance? So your `User` model inherits default behaviour from `DefaultUser`

```rb
class User < DefaultUser

end

class DefaultUser < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

You can include the `DefaultX` classes by making a gem to import in Gemfile that has all of these default classes defined.

Comment: That's easy enough, yes, but I'm trying to avoid having to define a User class at all, even as a stub inheriting from a default parent. I'm specifically looking for a way to have a class already defined, while still allowing the definitions in `/app/models` to also be loaded, even when the class already exists.

Comment: I'm suggestion you don't need the class to already exist, just the behaviour for the class. So the model in app/models/user.rb has some predefined behaviour b/c it inherits from `DefaultUser`. It's the same as if `User` was defined elsewhere (with some default behaviours) and behaviour added by app/models/user.rb. Or perhaps I'm still missing your point! Maybe you want it to be optional to define `User` in your app?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm after; I want it to be optional to define `User` in the app. One would only do so if they need to define behavior that strays from the predefined class.